# How do you execute a certain command if previous command returned error?

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm using Rselenium and I have `$clickElement()` which sometimes doesn't work, in which case I want R to do something else. I'm familiar with: `if(inherits(temp1, 'try-error')) {do something}` but I have no object in this case(`temp1`), so I'm not sure how to proceed.

This worked, but is obviously sloppy:

```
x <- "offending error message text"
if(x == geterrmessage()){do something}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Assumption: x is an element.

```
test <- try(x$clickElement(),silent=T)

if (class(test) == 'try-error'){
    ## do the error handling
}
```

Update: As suggested by @42-, you can write `if (class(test) == 'try-error')` as `if (inherits(test,'try-error'))`

Comment: Safer would be `if (inherits(test, 'try-error') )`. (Not my downvote. I thought `try` was the right direction to go)

Comment: @42- Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: I would be really happy if that downvoter can come up with a better answer. After all, we are all here to learn new things.

Comment: Thank you, and agreed, down voting with no explanation seems rude.